# Can't get URL parameter in doView

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

I have a Portlet deployed in IBM Portal Server 6.1 which has been mapped to a URL....
[image]

I'm trying to add a paramater to a URL like so...

```
http://localhost:10038/wps/myportal/StockOnHandPortlet?myParameter=false
```

And then read the parameter in my doView method like so...

```
         HttpServletRequest originalRequest = ((HttpServletRequest)((HttpServletRequestWrapper)request).getRequest());
         Enumeration params = originalRequest.getParameterNames();
         while(params.hasMoreElements()){
            String paramName = (String)params.nextElement();
            System.out.println(paramName + " = " + originalRequest.getParameter(paramName));
        }
```

But the parameter I've passed in my url is not in the request. i.e. Enumeration params is empty.

Can someone help me figure out on how I can fix this so that I can read a parameter in the URL inside doView?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleRequest;
import com.ibm.wps.engine.PortalRequestWrapper;
import com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portlet.PortletUtils;

HttpServletRequest r1 = PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest((RenderRequest) r);
PortalRequestWrapper r2 = (PortalRequestWrapper) r1;
ExtendedLocaleRequest r3 = (ExtendedLocaleRequest) r2.getRequest();
HttpServletRequest r4 = (HttpServletRequest) r3.getRequest();
return r4;
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: In doView method one can use the provided code to obtain the original HttpServletRequest. In this case r4 variable contains the original httpservletrequest, which one can use to obtain request parameters. But it should be mentioned, that it is not officially supported to get the original HttpServletRequest. Can you tell me what to clarify more?

Comment: Hi  Chernykh, Sorry I've taken so long to repond. When I try and import  Chernykh Alexander
ExtendedLocaleRequest and PortletUtils those classes do not exist in my libraries. I mad a mistake in my original post where I mentioned 6.1, I should have said portal server 6.0?

Comment: That's a big change. Portal 6.0 uses java 1.4. Well, I don't remeber exactly, but try to look here : http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Post_migration_considerations_ in **Portlets** section.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this using the following code...

```
/**
 * Get the original http request 
 * 
 * @param request the http request
 * @return the original http request
 */
private HttpServletRequest getHttpServletRequest(PortletRequest request){
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    while(httpServletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequestWrapper){
        HttpServletRequestWrapper httpServletRequestWrapper = (HttpServletRequestWrapper)httpServletRequest;
        httpServletRequest =  (HttpServletRequest)httpServletRequestWrapper.getRequest();
    }
    return httpServletRequest;
}
```